# Can a creature rip another creature's arms off?

Tags: dnd-5e, injury

My group is trying decide if we can or can not.

Comment: I'd suggest expanding the question to show some effort on your part. Explain why you think so, or why you don't.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your group is debating. Are you asking if someone can rip off someone else's arms with their bare hands? Are you asking if there's rules that cover arms-ripped-off injuries? Are you asking for advice on how a character could accomplish ripping arms off?

Comment: I think this is as straightforward a question can be and there's nothing wrong with it, the answer bellow from Dale M covers it perfectly. He wants to know if he can rip someone's arm off, he doen't care how, just if it's possible within the game and how he could do it.
No need to write a novel for a question like that.

Comment: @Manner Because RPGs take place in a fantasy space, you can pretty much do anything- the answer "sure, you can" is ok, but then the OP would need to ask again how they can do that, which is the real question, and the real question needs more details to be answered.

Comment: @Manner That is one possible interpretation. *My* first interpretation was “with bare hands”. Since between that and the interpretation the answer below uses, that's two incompatible meanings for the question. And that means the question is probably not clear enough to be ready for answering, which is what holds are for. Cheers!

Comment: Are you a player or are you the DM?  I edited your title to put the question in to game terms, since as it was written (and given Google searches) there might be someone mistaking it for RL bodily harm.

Comment: @Korvin We don't generally edit for that sort of thing, since so many titles here would need it and there's no real danger of misunderstanding.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie By all means revert if you feel that I have wronged the querent in this case.

Comment: @Korvin No worries, just heading off a scenario where we have to start intervening with well-meaning readers of that comment who start editing all our titles with unnecessary edits.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have been asked to edit for "triggers" on at least one occasion, by a mod, so I was exercising what I presume was due caution. Happy to learn that I was being overly cautious.

Comment: I'm ok with the edit -- this is the kind of situation we'd want to be clear which side of the player/character boundary we're talking about. ;) Though of course it's characters. ... I hope...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### If you want, sure

The basic rule of D&D is on p. 6 of the PHB.

> 1. The DM describes the environment. - "Here is a guy with arms."
> 2. The players describe what they want to do. - "I want to rip his arms off!"
> 3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’ actions. - "You rip his arms off."

### However, there is no mechanic in the rules that supports this

Combat in D&D is abstracted - "damage" occurs against a generic pool of hit points so there are no rules that cover targeting specific body parts or determining the effect of losing those parts.

If this is something you really want to do, there are RPGs that do deal with this. Or, you can come up with your own rules.

Comment: TC looks like he's a begginer at TRPGs so I think it would be nice to point him at some directions. There's the "Critical Hits Revisited", none of the critical options rips the arms, but they do cripple and could be tweaked to their tastes.

Comment: The link for Critical Hits Revisited is: https://sterlingvermin.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/critical-hits-revisited.pdf

Comment: Dale, isn't there some material in the DMG (optional rules) that deal with major injuries like this?  I am AFB or I'd toss in the page reference.

Comment: Injuries and lingering injuries, pages 272-273 DMG optional rules.